# .Net Core Web Api deployed successfully in AWS, but URL is not working

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

[image: Created a .Net Core Web App]

> Created a `.Net Core Web App`

`.Net Core web application` contains multiple projects, but I deployed an `API` project. Error : `HTTP ERROR 404` No webpage was found for the web address: http://....

[image]

> BeanStalk details are shown above.

[image]

> Amazon S3 details are shown above.
> My doubt is, there have some permission issue or URL need to qualify
> completely for API call.

[image]

> EC2 instance running fine.

[image]

> launchsettings.json

```css
{
  "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:19095",
      "sslPort": 44327
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DATABASE_NAME": "FYP",
        "PROFILE_COLLECTION_NAME": "Profiles",
        "MAIL_COLLECTION_NAME": "Mailes",
        "INTERESTSENT_COLLECTION_NAME": "InterestSents",
        "INTERESTRECIEVED_COLLECTION_NAME": "InterestRecieveds",
        "SEEN_COLLECTION_NAME": "Seens",
        "SHORTLIST_COLLECTION_NAME": "Shortlists",
        "SKIP_COLLECTION_NAME": "Skips",
        "CHATBOT_COLLECTION_NAME": "Chatbots",
        "MEMBERSHIP_COLLECTION_NAME": "Memberships",
        "NOTIFICATION_COLLECTION_NAME": "Notifications",
        "SETTINGS_COLLECTION_NAME": "Settings",
        "SUPPORT_COLLECTION_NAME": "Supports",
        "USERACTION_COLLECTION_NAME": "UserActions",
        "USERCHAT_COLLECTION_NAME": "UserChats",
        "VERIFICATION_COLLECTION_NAME": "Verifications"
      }
    },
    "Matrimony.Api": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "swagger",
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "DATABASE_NAME": "FYP",
        "PROFILE_COLLECTION_NAME": "Profiles",
        "MAIL_COLLECTION_NAME": "Mailes",
        "INTERESTSENT_COLLECTION_NAME": "InterestSents",
        "INTERESTRECIEVED_COLLECTION_NAME": "InterestRecieveds",
        "SEEN_COLLECTION_NAME": "Seens",
        "SHORTLIST_COLLECTION_NAME": "Shortlists",
        "SKIP_COLLECTION_NAME": "Skips",
        "CHATBOT_COLLECTION_NAME": "Chatbots",
        "MEMBERSHIP_COLLECTION_NAME": "Memberships",
        "NOTIFICATION_COLLECTION_NAME": "Notifications",
        "SETTINGS_COLLECTION_NAME": "Settings",
        "SUPPORT_COLLECTION_NAME": "Supports",
        "USERACTION_COLLECTION_NAME": "UserActions",
        "USERCHAT_COLLECTION_NAME": "UserChats",
        "VERIFICATION_COLLECTION_NAME": "Verifications"
      }
    }
  },
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:5001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

have you tried to enable any url for requests?

For example

```
ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001
Kestrel:EndPoints:Http:Url=http://+:5001
```

Here is the example on the appsettings.json file and link for [resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/endpoints?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

```
{
  "Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "Http": {
        "Url": "http://+:5001"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you are in a docker container, you could set it as an environment variable in the Dokerfile:

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001
ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
ENV Kestrel:EndPoints:Http:Url=http://+:5001
```

Comment: No, Where do I have to do this?  launchsettings.json or aws

Comment: Hi, you can put them on the appsettings.json file.
I have updated my answer.

Comment: I have updated the changes, still not working. Kindly check that.

Comment: This really solved my issue, and I could not find it mentioned anywhere in the deployment instruction of AWS. Thank you!